Universal property of Abelian-Jacobi Map/Jacobi variety for Riemann Surfaces
I have a question about universal property of Abel Jacobi Map and the Jacobi variety in the (classical) context of Riemann surfaces / complex smooth proper curves.
Let $C$ be such RS/complex sm curve $C$, $H^0(C, \Omega_C) \cong \mathbb{C}^g$ space of holomorphic forms generated by basis $\omega_1,..., \omega_g$, $H_1(C,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ the 1st homology group , and $p_0 \in C$ a fixed point. AJ map is the map
$$\begin{cases} u : C \to J(C);  \\ u(p) = \left( \int_{p_0}^p \omega_1, \dots, \int_{p_0}^p \omega_g\right) \bmod \Lambda \end{cases} $$
where  $J(C):=H^0(C, \Omega_C)^{\vee}/\Lambda$ for lattice  $\Lambda:=u(H_1(C,\mathbb{Z}))$.
Now it is claimed that $u$ resp $J(C)$ is claimed to be a precursor of Albanese variety, namely to satisfy following universal property:
Let $f:(C, p_0) \to (A,0,+) $ be a pointed map to a torus/complexAbelian variety (with group structure +) $A \cong \mathbb{C}^n/L$ for a lattice $L \cong  \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$, then $f$ factors through $(J(C),u)$.
Question: How to see with "classical methods" that $J(C)$ fullfils this universal property?
Ideas: There exist a regular birational map $b_g:C^g/ \text{Sym}(g) \to J(C), (p_1,..., p_g) \mapsto \sum_i \int_{p_0}^{p_i}$, so having a pointed map  $f:(C, p_0) \to (A,0) $   we can naively define a map $C^g/ \text{Sym}(g) \to A$ via $(p_1,..., p_g) \mapsto \sum_i f(p_i)$, so get a priori only a rational map $J(C) \to A$.
Is there an "elementary" argument why this rational map is even regular? If my naive approach I presented so far fails, how else one could show this universal property of $J(C)$ using only "classical" toolbox from theory of Riemann surfaces?
(It is known to me that it farly generalizable to world of schemes; here I would like only to develop intuition for classical viewpoint)

The map you call $b_g$ is more than just a rational map; it is a regular map which has a rational inverse.

@hunter: right thanks,  but as you wrote the inverse is only rational, and having once constructed the map $C^g/ \text{Sym}(g) \to A$ in the way as above (... this looks for me to be the most " natural" way to do this), the problem becomes to find the argument why the latter "decends" to $J(C)$. Do you see an argument?

ah got it, you are completely right.
